# Why is my bootstrap class style not applying

Tags: html, css, button

So I am newbie to HTML, CSS, and bootstrap and I am having trouble getting my stylesheet to update its values on my preview, and this is supposed to be my button tag and its value:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Find out More</button>
```

but when I try to change the style of the btn-xl value on my CSS,

```
.btn-xl {
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
```

Any changes I make would just not appear on my preview. Please someone tell me where I am getting all wrong?

So I tried checking my links maybe there was a mistake in the link title connecting my HTML and CSS, but there wasn't any mistake there.
I checked any typo that could conflict but it definitely isn't a typo, so I am completely lost at this point.

Comment: Might be, that one of the CSS for the other two classes also has padding in them and thus your change doesn't get applied.

Comment: is the method of calling your css file correct?

Comment: Yes, I called my CSS file correctly, my hover effect on the same button tag is applying, but the colors and other changes are not coming up. I also think that if the bootstrap class has padding already, my new input should override theirs, shouldn't it?

Comment: you can read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity. You need to add in more selector to increase your css's weight value

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having issues with the value being overwritten by bootstrap. Could be order you add the style sheets or it can be a specificity issue. If you change the class it would be

```css
.btn.btn-xl {
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Find out More</button>
```

If you want to change all the buttons, you can update the [variables bootstrap uses](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/#variables) for the padding.